# Can I paint a load center cover?

Tags: electrical, nec, us

I would like to paint the cover and door of my flush mount load center to match the wall color more closely. The manufacturer does offer a white in addition to the standard grey cover, but it is hard to find and ridiculously overprice.

Only the outside would be painted, so all labels on the inside would not get any overspray or anything else on them and would remain intact. I would also of course first remove the hinges and locking mechanism to ensure their operation wouldn't be affected.

Is this OK to do per NEC 2017 and with typical load center UL listings? Let me know if specifics are needed to answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is fine. The Electrical Code is silent on the issue, except for NEC 110.3B, which requires you to obey the unit's labeling and instructions.  So if they do not disallow painting the panel, then have fun.

**Do not cover up any labeling or numbering, and do not paint the breakers themselves**.

If you have a panel with no door, and you don't want to be looking at breakers, then contact electrical supply houses (not retail stores) until you find an authorized dealer for that brand of panel.  Ask them about panel covers with doors, or retrofit doors.  Paint the door.

The only exception is if your panel is the CH type.  Cutler Hammer's choice of color is pure perfection.  To make it match,  paint the rest of the house that color! :)

Comment: Eaton makes decorator covers for CH (and possibly BR as well) panels; also, you can get them custom-painted if you're willing to work with their Flex Center on a factory order...